# Difference between the 2 postgres statement

Tags: postgresql

```
ALTER TABLE rejected_events.rejected_events
    ADD COLUMN tenant_id smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
```

```
ALTER TABLE rejected_events.rejected_events
    ALTER COLUMN tenant_id DROP DEFAULT;
```

In my product, tenant_id  is set to 0 and then removed in next command as well.
I wonder what would be the intention of this strange stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Is this in a database migration/upgrade script?

The column is `tenant_id` so if previously there was only one user/tenant in the database it gives that tenant an id of 0.

In the future though you want any queries to specify a tenant. So, you keep the `NOT NULL` but drop the default.

Answer (score 0):

This is done because:

```
alter table varchar_test add column t_fld integer NOT NULL;
ERROR:  column "t_fld" of relation "varchar_test" contains null values
```

A `DEFAULT` is always specified for a column, by default that value is `NULL` per docs [CREATE TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html)

> DEFAULT default_expr

> The DEFAULT clause assigns a default data value for the column whose column definition it appears within. The value is any variable-free expression (in particular, cross-references to other columns in the current table are not allowed). Subqueries are not allowed either. The data type of the default expression must match the data type of the column.

> The default expression will be used in any insert operation that does not specify a value for the column. If there is no default for a column, then the default is null.

If you ran:

```
ALTER TABLE rejected_events.rejected_events
    ADD COLUMN tenant_id smallint NOT NULL
```

you would get the error I showed above. Adding the `DEFAULT 0` satisfies the `NOT NULL` constraint by adding `0` to the field for each existing row  in the table you are altering.  Then `ALTER COLUMN tenant_id DROP DEFAULT;` removes the `DEFAULT` for subsequent INSERTs. At that point you have to make sure a `NON-NULL` value is specified for the column.